# How can I handle the the Endpoint not found Exception just one time (WCF)

Tags: c#, wcf, error-handling, wcf-endpoint

As we know , when there was no connection between client and server, the Endpoint not found Exception will be created from WCF services ,

I d like to handle this error just one time and uses several times without  several try catches for each WCF services
please help me

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your server call in an Invoke method and handle the error there:

```
 public void Invoke(Action<T> call)
 {
    try
    {
       call();
    }
    catch(EndpointNotFoundException exception)
    {
    // handle here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, But the best way is providing a dynamic Proxcy

Comment: @arashAghajani how?